# Extending maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to generate a zip file assembly using the maven-assembly-plugin. There are only two problems I have left that I'm wondering if it's possible to solve with just configurations but as a last resort I am also considering writing my own maven plugin that extends the maven-assembly-plugin

The two missing pieces are

1. **Put each dependency that matches the include pattern into its own `outputDirectory`.**
   This is the relevant part of my assembly

   ```
   <moduleSet>
       <binaries>
           <dependencySets>
               <dependencySet>
                   <outputDirectory>module</outputDirectory>
                   <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
                   <includes>
                       <include>com.test.feature.*:*:jar</include>
                   </includes>
               </dependencySet>
           </dependencySets>
           <unpack>false</unpack>
       </binaries>
   </moduleSet>
   ```

   This will put all dependencies of the module with a groupId of `com.test.feature.*` in a folder called module. This works for me, like so

   ```
   module/
      com.test.feature.firstModule.jar
      com.test.feature.secondModule.jar
   ```

   What I need is a way to move each of the matching dependencies to its own folder, hopefully where the folder name is the artifactId of the dependency (not mandatory though)

   ```
   firstModule/
      com.test.feature.firstModule.jar
   secondModule/
      com.test.feature.secondModule.jar
   ```

   I know that I could create a `dependencySet` for each dependency, but the idea is to do this as future-proof as possible. If I create one for each, I will need to remember in the future to create a new set for every new artifact under com.test.feature. My biggest (but blind) hope is some kind of property ${dependencyName} that would be replaced for each dependency, which then I could use in the `outputDirectory`
2. **Generate an xml file with information about the dependencies and their folders**
   something like

   ```
   <module dir="firstModule" version="1.0-SNAPSHOT />
   <module dir="secondModule" version="2.1-SNAPSHOT />
   ```

   The generated xml will be part of the zip assembly

Can these two things, or one of them, be done with the vanilla assembly plugin? If not, is it possible to create a plugin that extends another? i have just seen tutorials for creating plugins [from scratch](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html), never to just add functionality to one of the standard plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:**
Use `artifactId` as parf ot `outputDirectory`'s value:

```xml
<outputDirectory>module/${artifact.artifactId}</outputDirectory>
```

**Q2:**
I think there is no ready solution. Write your own plugin ;)